# Do I need two trunk ports?

Tags: networking, switch, vlan

First time setting up a switch to have two networks on it. Going to separate the two networks through use of different vlans. Now for security purposes in order to keep the networks totally separate from each other do I need to create two trunk ports. One for the vlans of one network and another for the other network vlans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not need multiple trunk ports for separation. The packets will already be separated using their VLAN tags prefixed to each packet, which is actually the *whole point* of a trunk port.

(But the other end of the trunk port needs to go into a device that also understands VLAN tagging, e.g. an identical trunk port of another switch, or a VLAN-capable router.)

Due to tagging, each VLAN already is its own network (or subnet). There is no difference between VLANs of one network and VLANs of another, and their IDs have to be unique within the switch anyway (e.g. you can't have VLAN 5 of network A and VLAN 5 of network B).